# IEEEtrantools with TeXstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, ieeetran

I am using the IEEEtrantools package with TeXstudio. I have the problem that when writing an equation with

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}
    <formula>
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

it **marks all math commands red and complains 'math command outside math env'**. This is sad, because it looks a lot less beautiful and readable like this, which is in my opinion a big benefit of TeXstudio.

Any idea how to fix this? I have already included the `IEEEtrantools.cwl` file into the 'permanently active completion files' (according to this question: [TeXStudio doesn't recognize some commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47493/texstudio-doesnt-recognize-some-commands)) and it still does not work.

EDIT:

- TeX distribution: TeX Live 2015/Debian
- document class: scrreprt
- color related packages: color, graphicx, amsmath

In case it was not clear: the math commands appear red in the editor, no in the document.

Comment: @Mico see edit. Apologies for the insufficient information.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266286/117534

Comment: @Troy the linked question fixed my problem. i will mark this one as a duplicate